# Playwright timezone in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I'm running Playwright code in a Docker container on my Raspberry Pi. After taking a screenshot with Playwright, I noticed that the browser's timezone seems to be GMT instead of my local timezone CEST.

When running `date` on my Raspi, it returns:

```bash
myUser@myRaspi:~ $ date
Sun 11 Jun 16:17:55 CEST 2023
```

I've mounted my Raspi's timezone information into the container via volumes like this:

```
volumes:
  - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Now inside my Docker container, the timezone seems to be properly set:

```bash
root@b2c5d9540130:/app# date
Sun Jun 11 16:18:57 CEST 2023
```

However, when running the Playwright code, the screenshot still shows GMT time:
[image]

So how do I configure Playwright's Chromium so that it considers the Raspi's timezone?

Thx!

PS: [link to my project on GitHub](https://github.com/mu88/ScreenshotCreator/)

Answer (score 1):

playwright image is using as a *base* ubuntu.
Ubuntu is exposing ENV `TZ` so you can control which timezone to be available inside the container when it starts.

Use `ENV TZ="America/New_York"` inside `Dockerfile` or pass it as environment CLI flag when starting the container.

- Timezone short codes for TZ
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
- Add env variable to run command
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#env

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in my [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/mu88/ScreenshotCreator/blob/main/src/ScreenshotCreator.Api/Dockerfile), I'm using the ASP.NET Core image rather than Playwright

Comment: I think TZ is standard env / arg to change zone in most dockerized OS. As i see MS dotnet is using debian/ubuntu as base so it should works.

Comment: I've added `TZ="Europe/Zurich"` to my `docker-compose.yml`, but the screenshot is still GMT. Furthermore I noticed that `echo $TZ` on my Raspi returns nothing, so it does not seem to be set - since I want to consume my Raspi's timezone, there must be another way than `TZ`